# Getting Value of a Data Based on Column and Row Index

Tags: php, sql

For example my table CarTable

```
CARS  COLOR  STOCK
Honda  Blue    3
Toyota Red     5
```

I want to be able to select "5". Ie, i want to select item in STOCK column
based on the row index (in this case, I know the index is 1).

I tried:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT STOCK FROM CarTable WHERE ROW=1");
```

Result seems to be nil.
No other error seen in Chrome console either. I am totally new in this hope you can help me.

Comment: `SELECT STOCK FROM CarTable WHERE Stock=5`?

Comment: You want to display `STOCK` based on what? either `COLOR` or `CARS`...

Comment: @YashParekh based on second row alone. (ie row index)

Comment: The idea of a row index in a SQL table isn't quite right - the idea of SQL is that you have meaningful keys associated with the rows, so for example - in your case you may be more interested in a row where the column CARS = 'Toyota'

Comment: Nah man. That value is not fixed. Any user is able to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that using the [LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) clause, like this :

```
SELECT STOCK FROM CarTable LIMIT 1, 1
```

This query will return the `STOCK` of the second line of your table.

**Explanation :**

`LIMIT` clause can take 2 arguments : *the first row index*, *the number of rows to return*, so if we want to get the records starting from the 2nd row, we set the first parameter to **1** (2-1), and if we want only one row to be returned, we set the second parameter to **1**.

Another example, this query will return only 10 records, start on record 16:

```
SELECT STOCK FROM CarTable LIMIT 15, 10
```

This is an [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/718420/1) <<<< CHECK IT!

Comment: can you explain what is the two 1s?

Comment: anyway I tried it and it doesn't work. not sure why.

Comment: @GeneCode, i edited my answer adding an explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Hamza. Your code works in SQL fiddle. But when I put into my code it doesn't work. There is something wrong in my side. Anyway i accept this answer.

Comment: This answer is completely unreliable - using LIMIT without any ORDER BY will mean that it can return any row in the database.

Comment: @NigelRen for my case the order is fixed really. so it is ok.

Comment: With a SQL database there is no fixed order, it's up to you what you do with your questions.  But as you pointed out yourself, it doesn't work in your code.  Read up a bit more about SQL databases, about indexes and keys it will make more sense in the long term.

Comment: No. it works now. Actually it wasn't working due to other issue and not this.